# Grep Only returns first matching result (not desired). How do I prevent this?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file a.txt with the following content

```
>abc
123456789
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
>jkl
12
```

I want to get only those line that have **4-6 numeric characters, along with the line preceding it**. In this case, the desired answer is

```
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
```

I understand that grep will insert '--' between two adjacent lines when using `-B`, but let's ignore that for now. I tried

`grep -x "[^>].\{4,6\}" a.txt`

But this return me with only the first matching result and then stops. That is I only have

```
>def
123456
```

as my result. I tried going through `man` page and walked through the relevant man, but no help. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Print only whole lines containing from 4 to 6 digits and one line before each match (`-B1`):

```sh
grep -B1 -x '[0-9]\{4,6\}' a.txt
```

Example:

```sh
% cat a.txt
>abc
123456789
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
>jkl
12

% grep -B1 -x '[0-9]\{4,6\}' a.txt
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
```

The expression that you used, `[^>].\{4,6\}`, is not doing what you intend. The `[^>]` matches one character that is not a `>`. Then the `.\{4,6\}` matches four to six sequences of any characters. Since one character was already matched with `[^>]`, matching entries will have from 5 to 7 characters. So `123456` matches but `1234` does not.

The expression `[^>].\{3,5\}` would also work as intended, but `[0-9]\{4,6\}` expresses the intention more clearly.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I forgot to type the -B1 in question's code despite mentioning it theoretically. I don't see any difference in your code apart from the -B1 and [0-9], still getting the same undesired results. Thank you!

Comment: By `undesired results` do you mean you only get 2 lines as you shown in the question instead of 4?

Comment: Ok, you will get such results if you use `grep -x "[^>].\{4,6\}" a.txt`. Use `grep` command that @gustgr suggested in their answer above.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include an explanation on why the attempt shown in the question fails. @GordonDavisson gave the same explanation in an answer of his own shortly before I did it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I gave up and came back to the problem again. Realized the exact same thing that @gustgr mentioned in his edit.

Comment: I do not know how to accept an answer, but I did upvote the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by using `awk`

```
awk '/^[0-9]{4,6}$/ {print a"\n"$0} {a=$0}' file
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
```

- `/^[0-9]{4,6}$/` if line as 4 to 6 digits, then:
- - `{print a"\n"$0}` print variable a and print the current line
- `a=$0` set `a` to current line, so it can be used in next lines operation.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by using sed.

```
sed -ne '/^[0-9]\{4,6\}$/{x;G;p};h' a.txt
>def
123456
>ghi
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that your regular expression isn't doing what you want. The regex "`[^>].\{4,6\}`" matches a single character that isn't ">" (the "`[^>]`" part), *followed by* 4 to 6 characters ("`[^>].\{4,6\}`"). Since the not-a-">" character isn't included in the 4 to 6, that's a total of 5 to 7 characters, and therefore doesn't match "1234". It also *would* match "1234567", which you don't want.

If you want 4-6 numeric characters, the standard form (in "basic" regex syntax) would be "`[[:digit:]]\{4,6\}`"

```
$ grep -B1 -x "[[:digit:]]\{4,6\}" a.txt
>def
123456
--
>ghi
1234
```